# Why does this prints Invalid Credentials instead of Logged In

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am learning Python. I have this [code](https://repl.it/repls/NotableSmoothOutput#main.py):

```
import csv

# Asking for user Inputs
user_name = input('Enter Username: ')
password = input('Enter Password: ')


def login(user_name, password):
    # Opening the CSV File
    with open('user_info.csv', 'r') as user_info_file:
        # Defining the file reader
        csv_reader = csv.reader(user_info_file)

        # Checking if the user credentials are correct
        for user in csv_reader:

            # Checking if the user_name and password are in the csv file
            if user[0] == user_name and user[1] == password:
                return True

    return False


authenticate = login(user_name, password)
if authenticate == True:
    print('Logged In')
else:
    print("Wrong Credentials")
```

When I enter the username and password same as the one in the csv file it is printing `Invalid Credentials` instead of `Logged in`.

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: have you tried to `print(user)` to see what values you're comparing?

Comment: Yes it prints [username, password]

Comment: Use `print(user)` in your loop and see what's wrong. Did you really enter a space as the first character of your password? If I enter `user_one` and `password_one` (leading space!) it works for me.

Comment: If `user[0] == user_name and user[1] == password` is never true, then the strings you're comparing are never true. Try `print(list(user[0]), list(user[1]))` to ensure that there isn't a newline or something else "invisible" in the read strings.